# install R library e1071 manually

Tags: software-installation, r

I need to install e1071 library manually. I downloaded the latest package of the same. But configure, though successful and without errors, doesn't create a makefile.

```
./configure does the following:

checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wanted to install `e1071` manually, then I would simply fire up `RStudio`, then install the package from their interface. If that doesn't suit you, you can download the `.tar.gz` source package [from CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/), then in RStudio `Install packages > From local file`.

The package needs to be installed from *within* R, so running `./configure` manually is discouraged. You should be using `install.packages()` instead.

Comment: I downloaded the .tar.gz. and ran ./configure. and then i am stuck..

Comment: Don't do that. Read again my solution, and try that.

Answer (score 0):

1. first download the package off the following URL into, say, `~/Downloads`

   https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/e1071_1.6-6.tar.gz
2. type "R" in shell/terminal

   ```
   $ sudo R
   ```
3. Type in the following command:

   ```
   install.packages("~/Downloads/e1071_1.6-6.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
   ```

   N.B. This installs the package into default library. To see the default library in R type in

   ```
   .Library
   ```

   or

   ```
   .libPaths()
   ```

   the site library is repoted by:

   ```
   .Library.site
   ```

   To avoid installation into the default library (/usr/lib/R/library) you may insteas type in:

   ```
   install.packages("~/Downloads/e1071_1.6-6.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source", lib="/your-prefered-path/")
   ```

Comment: NOTE: in general, you do not need sudo to install R packages. Starting R as regular user (just `R`, not `sudo R`) is sufficient. You'll be prompted to install packages to a personal library.